# Django - Stuck On Creating a Pricing System

Tags: python, django, model, business-logic

> I am making a "booking airbnb" website.

On my apartment detail page, I have a JQuery UI Date Picker calendar which the user uses to put in start and end dates of the reservation.

Once that is done and the user submits the form I want to refresh the whole site, and when refreshed display the dates that the user picked earlier, as long with price per day and total price.

In my models I have created:

models.py:

```py
class Apartment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    apartment_price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField()
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ApartmentImages(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="image")
    image = models.ImageField("image")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url


class ApartmentPrices(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, on_delete="models.CASCADE", related_name="price")
    price_start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price_end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.apartment.title

class Reservation(models.Model):
    apartment = models.ForeignKey(Apartment, related_name='reservations',
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(default="", max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

this is what I have in my view so far. I have tried many different things, but I'm stuck on the logic on how is this supposed to work.

here is my view :

```py
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    prices = ApartmentPrices.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    context = {}
    context['apartment'] = apartment
    context['prices'] = prices

    # svi datumi za cijene
    price_dates = []
    for start, end, price in prices.values_list('price_start_date', 'price_end_date', 'price'):
        while start <= end:
            price_dates.append(start.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y'))
            price_dates.append(price)
            start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)


    unavailable = []
    for start, end in apartment.reservations.values_list('start_date', 'end_date'):
        while start <= end:
            unavailable.append(start.strftime('%-d-%m-%Y'))
            start += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    form = ReservationForm()
    context['unavailable_dates'] = json.dumps(unavailable)
    context['form'] = form

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ReservationForm()

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.apartment = apartment
            reservation.save()
            form.save()
            return render(request, "booking/apartment.html", context)


    return render(request, 'booking/apartment.html', context)
```

So could anyone help me figure out what would be the best way to compare user picked dates to the price dates in the DB and get the price?

Thanks so much, been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: Do you really want to refresh or you didn't know about AJAX before?

Comment: Hey Tiago, thanks for answering. I really need to refresh, I'm not supposed to use JS/AJAX. It all has to be done all in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give Appartment a method to fetch the price where a given date object is is between start and end date.
(untested)

```py
...
from django.db.models import Q


class Apartment(models.Model):
    ...
    def price_by_date(self, date_obj):
        """returns the first price with date_obj is between start and end date

        Args:
            date_obj(datetime.date): the date of the price you want

        Returns:
            ApartmentPrices: first valid price found
        """
        # self.price is a back reference to all prices with self as apartment
        # you named it by giving related_name="price" in ApartmentPrices.apartment
        return self.price.filter(
            Q(price_start_date__lte=date_obj) & Q(price_end_date__gte=date_obj)
        ).first()
    ...
```

In the view you should be able to do:

```py
...
def apartment_view(request, apartment_id):

    reservation = Reservation.objects.filter(apartment__pk=apartment_id)
    apartment = get_object_or_404(Apartment, pk=apartment_id)
    date_price = apartment.price_by_date(datetime.date(2019, 10,18))
    # date_price.price would be the integer
    ...
```

Further information:

[Q - queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) are used to combine the two queries (start + end) to one query.

Comment: Thanks Frank !
Can you please explain how this works in a few words ?
I'm still a begginer, this is my first method on a model lol

Comment: I also get : 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'price' when I try to do Apartment.price_by_date(request.POST, end_date)

Comment: it needs an instance of Apartment.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out haha. Thanks !
But with "Apartment.price_by_date(Apartment, end_date)"  I get : 'ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: wait please i'm creating sample data

Comment: Can you try it this way? Be careful if you do Apartment.price_by_date(request.POST, end_date) you access the class, not the instance. In your view your instance is called apartment with small a.

Comment: When I do this, all I get back from the query is the apartment title, in this case ""28 West St"

Comment: what says tape(returned_object)? It would be correct if it shows the title because it is returned by your __str__. Normally it should be an ApartmentPrices object

Comment: i meant '_ _ str_ _'-method of ApartmentPrices

Comment: Should I remove it completely ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a problem. The only thing is that the ApartmentPrices object you got returned by price_by_date is called "28 West St" now but it is a object, work with it ;-) Or do you want to have only the price as integer? then you only need to access the attribute 'price' from your object. date_price.price in my example.